# Are there any online writing groups dedicated to critiquing synopses?

Tags: novel, synopsis

I wrote what others believe is a killer query letter, but now I have to do a synopsis. There appear to be lots of writer's groups, but I was hoping for a free one that focuses on reading synopses.
https://janefriedman.com/find-the-right-critique-group/
http://www.critiquecircle.com/forums.asp?action=viewforum&index=247

Critique Circle does a great job with query letters and a few writers do post their synopsis at that site. Are there groups available for submitting synopses for writers to critique?

Comment: Other than Critique Circle I have yet to find a group dedicated to reviewing synopses, but I did find this very useful template that uses an example to clarify its use. It really helped me focus on the Core Plot. I hope it helps others as much as it is helping me: http://www.publishingcrawl.com/2012/04/17/how-to-write-a-1-page-synopsis/

Answer (score 1):

I have used [www.scribophile.com](http://www.scribophile.com) in the past to get critiques for short stories and other pieces of writing with decent success.

A quick search through the site's Groups area and I found the [www.scribophile.com/groups/query-and-synopsis-crit-trades/](http://www.scribophile.com/groups/query-and-synopsis-crit-trades/) group, but the forums on the site are also a good place to ask.

Hope this helps and happy writing :)